# post_row_actions filter is not working while update post using quick edit

Tags: filters, quick-edit

I have created two links using post_row_actions, it was displaying fine when page loads. But the links will get disappear after update post using quick-edit. Is it a bug from WordPress or did I miss something. My code will look like given below.

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'add_new_link', 10, 2);

public function add_new_link($actions, $page_object)
{
    $actions['new_action'] = '<a href="'.admin_url().'post.php?id='.$page_object->ID.'&action=new-action">New Action</a>'; 
    return $actions;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: As a sidenote: `admin_url()` takes two parameters: `$path` and `$scheme`. The first one would then be: `admin_url("post.php?id={$page_object->ID}&action=new-action");` or `add_query_arg( 'action', 'new-action', admin_url("post.php?id={$page_object->ID}") );`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the question as I found out it is my mistake.  It is happened because I disabled the admin object of my plugin while doing ajax(by mistake), it cause the issue of not processing "post_row_actions"(I defined in admin class) in quick-edit.

Thank you for your help.